# How to modify jenkins Web Interface to pick artifacts to publish?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, publish, artifacts

I have an project to upgrade my jenkins. So the problem is I use jenkins plugins called "Publish over ssh". As I read that plugin can publish our artifactory file to another server by ssh connection. But in the configuration it always run after our job finised. So every jobs that I run, always publish to server.

So, I want to ask, how can I pick which build history artifacts that I want to publish? and it can publish when I want to publish. And then I have an Idea to adding button in jenkins web interface, to trigger adding job configuration, build it, and publish it over SSH. But, I don't know how to modify jenkins web interface. My server use tomcat, that run java ".war" file.

So, do you all have suggestion for my problem, how to modify jenkins web interface, or how to pick certain build artifacts?

Thanks...